# How can I describe this data using a graph?

Tags: temperature, precipitation

[image]

I want to know how I can put all this data into one graph. I thought that temperature can be graphed as a bar graph and precipitation could be used with a line graph. However I don't know how i can include all four cities.

Comment: You make four lines, and four bars next to each other. But that is a lot of visual data, so you'd better think about *what* you want to display and *why* - you're not telling us.

Comment: Either one graph per city, or one graph per topic. Otherwise it'd be too much information and not easily decipherable.

Comment: Furthermore, I would display temperature with a line and precipitation with bars

Comment: thanks everyone.@JanDoggen this is what I was thinking to do.